# Highcharts-browserify desn't work

Tags: highcharts, browserify

error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

But, I download the highcharts.src.js from http://www.highcharts.com/, and change the code at line 1201 from `win.jQuery` to `$`, add `var $ = require('jquery');`, then it work with browserify.

It's here something wrong?  Thank you

Comment: Which jquery version you use?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.3, Thank you

Comment: Problem solve, It seem something about browserify-shim with jQuery, config in browserify package.json, highcharts-browserify  work well~

Comment: Post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is helpful to anyone else, I got this working by add this to my package.json:

```
{   
    ...,
    "browser": {
        "Highcharts": "./vendor/highcharts/highcharts.js",
        "HighchartsMore": "./vendor/highcharts/highcharts-more.js",
        "HighchartsAdapter": "./vendor/highcharts/standalone-framework.js"
    },
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            "browserify-shim"
        ]
    },
    "browserify-shim": {
        "Highcharts": {
            "depends": ["HighchartsAdapter:HighchartsAdapter"],
            "exports": "Highcharts"
        },
        "HighchartsMore": {
            "depends": ["Highcharts:Highcharts"]
        },
        "HighchartsAdapter": {
            "exports": "HighchartsAdapter"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Small correction in the browser alias:  `"HighchartsAdapter": "./vendor/highcharts/adapters/standalone-framework.js"`

Comment: Thanks. I'd used non-standard paths, but your suggestion will work for the Highcharts path structure.

Answer (score 0):

It seem something about browserify-shim with jQuery, config in browserify package.json, highcharts-browserify work well~